# Ruby regex for masking sensitive information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails project and I am using gem `http_logger` and I need to mask sensitive information in the request headers and request body and response.

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters
```

do not work in this because because I make a request outside of rails request in a separate thread.

I need a way to replace "access_token" and "client_secret" within a string with [FILTERED]

Example strings:

```
Response body   {"access_token":[FILTERED],"scope":"create:foo","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

or

```
Request body   {"client_id":"fn23uf32u9f34","client_secret":[FILTERED],"audience":"audience","grant_type":"client_credentials"}
```

I am fine having two separate regular expressions for both cases.

Comment: I've just figured out I can also split the string by colon, find an index by the key, grab the value of the next index and replace it with [FILTERED] and then join the array back into a string :)

Comment: In your edit you give the desired result for each of two examples but do not show the two original strings from which those two strings were produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression:

```
rgx = /("(?:access_token|client_secret)":)"[^"]+"/
```

in

```
str.sub(rgx, '\1[FILTERED]')
```

---

```
str = 'Response body   {"access_token":"oigoi34oi34thj3489we89e2","scope":"create:foo","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}'
```

```
puts str.sub(rgx, '\1[FILTERED]')
```

displays

```
Response body   {"access_token":[FILTERED],"scope":"create:foo","expires_in":86400,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

```
str = 'Request body   {"client_id":"fn23uf32u9f34","client_secret":"jibberish","audience":"audience","grant_type":"client_credentials"}'
```

```
puts str.sub(rgx, '\1[FILTERED]')
```

displays

```
Request body   {"client_id":"fn23uf32u9f34","client_secret":[FILTERED],"audience":"audience","grant_type":"client_credentials"}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1xkSf/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(                  # begin capture group 1      \ 
  "                # match literal
  (?:              # begin non-capture group
    access_token   # match literal
    |              # or
    client_secret  # match literal
  )
  ":               # match literal
)
"                  # match literal 
[^"]+              # match one or more characters other than
                   # double-quotes, as many as possible
"                  # match literal
```

Comment: You are a genius :) Would you please explain it to me how all that works?

Comment: I've revised my answer. Please tell me if this now satisfies your requirements. I deleted my previous (now-irrelevant) comments and suggest you do the same.